# Typescript/Angular - Create a list from a property in an object array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Starter code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mgqhua

I have an array of objects:

```
  public arr = [
    {a: 1,    b:2},
    {a: 11,   b:22},
    {a: 111,  b:222},
    {a: 1111, b:2222},
  ]
```

I want to 'filter' out the values of `a` in the array so that I can get a new list from it `list_of_a_values = [1, 11, 111, 1111]`

What's the simplest way to do this? Is there a simple javascript method like `Array.filter()` that can do this?

Comment: `arr.map(({a}) => a)`

Comment: Thanks, this works!

Comment: Actually, this should be a duplicate of [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19590865/215552).

Answer (score 3):

Try the [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method.

```js
var arr = [ {a: 1, b:2}, {a: 11, b:22}, {a: 111,  b:222}, {a: 1111, b:2222} ]

console.log(arr.map(item => item.a));
```

Comment: Thanks, this works!